# ExtJs load package on demand

Tags: extjs, package, loader

I need to load entire package on demand. This includes JS and CSS. Package is build up and ready.

Is there any way to do that?

ExtJs 5.0.1

Comment: Do you mean package as created and built with Sencha Cmd? `sencha generate package ...` and `sencha package build`?

Comment: @Saki Yes, package is generated like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building the package with `sencha package build` creates `build` directory in which you can find resultant javascript files, such as:

```
build/package.js
build/package-debug.js
```

where "package" is the actual package name.

Similarly, CSS and resources are placed in

```
build/resources/package-all.css
build/resources/package-all-debug.css
```

Loading the package would actually mean to load `build/package.js` and `build/resources/package-all.css` at runtime.

The implementation is also easy: inject appropriate script and stylesheet link tags in the page head.

You can find an example of loading css at runtime here: http://extjs.eu/examples/#theme-colors

Comment: Yes, it works. Was hoping for Ext.Loader.loadModule() method.